# Definition of the filtered normalized chain complex $N_0A$

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

At the page 163 of [the book Simplicial Homotopy Theory by Goerss and Jardine](http://dodo.pdmi.ras.ru/%7Etopology/books/goerss-jardine.pdf), the first sentence starts with "Observe that $N_0A= A$, that ...". According to the further calculation in that page and the original definition at the page before, it looks like $N_0A_0 = A_0$ however $N_0A_n=kerd^n_0 \neq A_n$. Am I missing something? Or is this just a typo with a quick fix that I can't see?

Definition given in the book is as follows:
$A_n$ is any simplicial abelian group and
$$N_jA_n =
\begin{cases}
\bigcap^j_{i=0} \text{ker$(d_i)$}  & \text{for $ n \geq j+2$,} \\
NA_n & \text{for $n \leq j+1$.}
\end{cases}
$$

Here $NA_n$ is the n-th component of the normalized chain complex, so $NA_n = \bigcap^{n-1}_{i=0}\text{$d_i$} \subset A_n $, and maps $d_i$ have the domain $A_n$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This needs [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960): what are $N_0$ and $A_n$? The reader cannot be expected to have access to the book you cite.

Comment: @robjohn context added.

Comment: (+1) This is a good example of context added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After solving [this exercise sheet](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/REU2016/Normalized.pdf) about the normalized chain complex,
it seems like the definition is given for $N_{j+1}A_n$ in the book. Which makes $N_0A = A$ indeed. So it should have been:
$$N_jA_n =
\begin{cases}
\bigcap^{j-1}_{i=0} \text{ker$(d_i)$}  & \text{for $ n \geq j+1$,} \\
NA_n & \text{for $n \leq j$.}
\end{cases}
$$
Similar indexing typo is made throughout the construction of the chain homotopy that would prove Theorem 2.4. But the main idea is completely same.